# @capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning doesn't open front camera in my Ionic capacitor project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, qr-code, google-mlkit

I have a small project. I am constantly reading qr code and making transactions. I have a problem here. I try to open the front camera and read the qr code, but it only opens the rear camera every time. How can I fix this problem?

Example code:

```
import { Barcode, BarcodeScanner as mlkit, LensFacing, BarcodeFormat, BarcodeScannerPlugin  } from '@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning';

async scan2(){
    const granted = await this.requestPermissions2();
    if (!granted) {
      this.presentAlert2();
      return;
    }
    //const { barcodes } = await mlkit.scan({lensFacing: LensFacing.Back});
    document.querySelector('ion-content').classList.add('test');
    let  barcodes  = await (await mlkit.scan({lensFacing: LensFacing.Front, formats: [BarcodeFormat.QrCode]})).barcodes[0].displayValue;
    console.log(barcodes)
    console.log("barcodessssss")
    this.barcode = barcodes;
    
    if(this.barcode)
    {     
      mlkit.stopScan();
      document.querySelector('ion-content').classList.remove('test');
      await this.setOpen(true);
    }
        
  }
```

Ionic Info:

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1
> (C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)    Ionic
> Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.3.0
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.2.0    @angular-devkit/schematics
> : 16.2.0    @angular/cli                  : 16.2.0
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 9.0.0
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI      : 5.2.3    @capacitor/android : 5.2.3
> @capacitor/core    : 5.2.3    @capacitor/ios     : not installed
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.15.4    native-run  : 1.7.2
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v18.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
> 9.4.0    OS     : Windows 10

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.